# AngularJS: Mock exception handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I've added the following code to my Angular config to handle exceptions

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    return function(exception, cause) {
      // Awesome custom error handling
    }
  }])
});
```

But how do I prevent unit tests entering this? Can I mock this part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$exceptionHandler mock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$exceptionHandler), like mentioned in the AngularJS docs:

> In unit tests, if angular-mocks.js is loaded, this service is overridden by mock $exceptionHandler which aids in testing.

Here is a implementation which hopefully provides inspiration:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$exceptionHandler

Cheers mate